# MongoDB: javascript execution failed : can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, exception

In MongoDb , when i try to modify existing document in collection , it generate the following exception : `javascript execution failed : can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js`

In mongoDb shell i perform the following action :

```
 > var doc1 = db.users.find({name:"Harmeet"})
 > doc1.color = "Blue"
 > db.users.save(doc1)
```

when call to the save method the exception thow.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use
`var doc1 = db.users.findOne({name:"Harmeet"})`

`db.users.find` returns a cursor.

Answer (score 3):

Although @Manuel Rony Gomes has answer the question, when you want to insert multiple documents found from collection A into collection B at once, you can use the toArray() to let it work:

```
db.coll_B.insert(db.coll_A.find({}).toArray())
```