# embed existing document in new document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to insert a new document in my collection "companies", and embed an existing document from the collection "users".

What I tried is

```
db.companies.insert( { "_id": 2, name: "sample-com", admin: db.users.find({  "_id": 1 }) } )
```

but it doesn't work

> "can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:143")

How do I embed the existing document in my new document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: javascript execution failed : can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041356/mongodb-javascript-execution-failed-cant-save-a-dbquery-object-at-src-mongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [**`.findOne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

```js
var admin = db.users.findOne({  "_id": 1 });
db.companies.insert({ "_id": 2, "name": "sample-com", "admin": admin })
```

Comment: thanks! works very well. I didn't noticed that I can use variables in the mongo-shell. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @Surras Yes you can because [the mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript shell for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)